# Insert Formula into Google sheets column by using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I wanted to Insert a Formula to a particular column of the google sheets, please excuse me I have no experience with sheets or apps script but i need the help of both to make my android app working, so say i have this column CMP where i want to insert my google finance formula to compute the ccurrent price of the company name given in column under Company name and at the current time there are 3 rows so it should update the column header under CMP for all the rows present in the sheet with the formula to compute the current price, pic for the sheets:
[image]

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question and assuming you are using tickers in your company name column, you should be able to get your desired results without a formula.  Just copy the following GOOGLEFINANCE formula down your CMP column:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2)
```

If you do not want to have error messages where the company name cell is empty use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2),"")
```